# How to change innodb_autoinc_lock_mode variable per user on cPanel server?

Tags: mysql

I want to change the MySQL variable innodb_autoinc_lock_mode from the default value 1 to 0, as it is causing problems with auto-increment ids gaps in apps that query using INSERT IGNORE etc.

I know it can be changed for all the server via adding the setting:

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

inside file:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

But is it possible to do this on per user, like for example it happens with php.ini file, on a cPanel/WHM shared hosting account ???

I have tried setting a file with the variable and value:

```
/home/username/.my.cnf
/home/username/my.cnf
/home/username/etc/.my.cnf
/home/username/etc/my.cnf
```

None of them seems to work, any ideas how this can be done, either through setting file per user or via phpMyAdmin etc ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) is a global (not session) variable, and is read-only at runtime.

It is impossible for multiple connections to the same MySQL server to have different values for this variable under any circumstances.

Additionally, I'm not sure setting this value to 0 does what you think it does with regard to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements.  If it really does avoid lost values that are allocated but unneeded, then the documentation is very unclear on this point.

Comment: thanks for the response, the setting does indeed what is suggested on my original post, I have tested as root the setting in my.cnf

although the documentation is unclear that the value 0 does prevent autoinc gaps in case of insert ignore, which does increase counter in case of failed insertion (this is really strange btw and should not happen by design, but it does!), which seems to be fixed when innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0 is configured.

so, concluding, it is not possible to set global variables per user by any means ?

Comment: When a variable is *global only* -- like this one -- that's correct: there is one value for the entire server.  Some variables are both global and session -- and usually, in that case, you get the global value when you connect, but can change it in your session (connection).  If you think about it, this is a **lock mode** so if different users on different connections could have different values, that would defeat the entire purpose of the variable, which ensures that all connections use a compatible locking mode and don't trash each other's inserts.